# How do get headphones and speakers output from the rear panel?

Tags: speakers, headphones

I just want to be able to switch to headphones and speakers, for example in daylight I dislike headphones but in the night I would like to wear them.

I could do that, simply plugging headphones to the front panel and speakers to the rear panel

But I don't like the cable and all that in front of my pc, I want everything coming from the rear panel of my pc

is this posible?

Right now i have the mic of my headphones into the " mic in (rear panel) and the speakers and audio output of headphones plugged into this

[image]

A Headphone splitter, so I muted my TV in the night to hear only headphones.

Mobo: ASUS P8XZ77-V-pro HD audio.

Comment: is there a way to make the rear or side speaker out, like the same one of the front speaker out, so i plug speaker into front and headphones into rear/side??

Comment: Can you supply a little more info on your speaker configuration? 5.1? Quad?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot switch from headphones to speakers and speakers to headphones on the rear panel on the same Speakers-Out port. This is because:

- The attachment is exterior to the motherboard.
- It cannot control or switch over a cable which is just a splitter or acts like one.

**What you can do is:**

- Attach your speakers to the Line-Out port at the rear.
- Attach your headphones to the Speakers-Out port at the rear.
- And then use your sound control panel to use any one, or use both.

Comment: but there's only on output wich is the green one, the other ones are side(grey)   the rear (black)          orange(subwoffer)
mic in(pink) front speaker out(green)  line in(blue

Comment: the black rear port can be changed to line-out through your realtek sound control panel if your speaker system is NOT configured as 5.1 surrond.

Answer (score 0):

If you a rear usb port, you can get a usb audio [dongle](http://www.usbgear.com/USBG-X2X.html) and switch outputs as necessary in the audio panel in the tasktray.